# Change label text with spring:message

Tags: jquery

I want to change the text of my label with jquery like :

```
$('#mylabel').text(<spring:message code="mytext" text="mytext" />);
```

But all I get is a ReferenceError: TestText is not defined.

TestText is the value behind my message code. Can anybody tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the value is a string literal it should be enclosed with in `''`

```
$('#mylabel').text('<spring:message code="mytext" text="mytext" />');
```